# got oslo-vmware install error

Tags: python, linux, openstack, devstack

when running devstack on my computer, with CentOS 7. I got this. Anybody can give me some help?

#

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 348, in move_wheel_files
    assert info_dir, "%s .dist-info directory not found" % req
AssertionError: oslo-vmware .dist-info directory not found
##########################################
```